# Entity Framework left join on two nullable columns results in unwanted OR is not null condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following sample query:

```
from reasonCodes in _context.ReasonCodes
join mapping in _context.MappedCodes on
new {
    ReasonCode = reasonCodes.Code, StateUid = filter.StateID, VendorUid = filter.VendorID, MappingType = filter.MappingTypeID
}
equals
new {
    ReasonCode = mapping.ValueToMap, StateUid = mapping.StateUid, VendorUid = mapping.VendorUid, MappingType = mapping.Type
}
into mappingInner
from mapping in mappingInner.DefaultIfEmpty()
join emp in _context.Employees on mapping.ModifiedBy equals emp.UseraccountUid into empInner
from emp in empInner.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new MappingSearchResult {
    ReasonCode = reasonCodes.Code,
        MappedReasonCode = mapping.MappedCode
    DateModified = (mapping != null) ? mapping.ModifiedDate : null,
        ModifiedBy = (mapping != null) ? (emp != null ? emp.Emplname + ", " + emp.Empfname : null) : null
};
```

My issue is that in the left join for Employees, both ModifiedBy on the MappedCodes table and UseraccountUid on the Employees table are nullable GUIDs. EF is generating an extra statement as part of this join:

```
OR (
    ([MappedCodes].[ModifiedBy] IS NULL)
     AND ([Employees].[useraccount_uid] IS NULL)
)
```

This is resulting in thousands of rows being returned, when I am expecting about 15 when there is no data in MappedCodes. My idea is I want all codes from the ReasonCodes table returned in my query, plus any existing extra data from the MappedCodes and Employees tables if applicable. So if MappedCodes is empty, I should only see ReasonCode populated in the SELECT. However, this generated OR statement is messing the query up due to joining on two nullable columns.

If I write this directly in SQL it does what I want, but I'm not sure how to write this in LINQ.

Comment: Hello, maybe you could edit your question to include your working SQL query

Comment: Which EF version?